# expss table with row percentage within nested variables in R

Tags: r, expss

When using the expss package in R for creating tables, how does one get the row_percentages to be calculated within a nested variable? In the example below, I would like the row percentage to be calculated within each time period. Thus, I would like the row percentage to sum to 100% within each time period (2015-2016 and 2017-2018). Now however, the percentage is calculated over the entire row.

```r
library(expss)

data(mtcars)

mtcars$period <- "2015-2016"
mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
mtcars$period[33:64] <- "2017-2018"

mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      period = "Measurement period"
)

mtcars %>% 
  tab_cells(cyl) %>% 
  tab_cols(period %nest% am) %>% 
  tab_stat_rpct(label = "row_perc") %>% 
  tab_pivot()
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
 |                     |              |          | Measurement period |        |              |        |
 |                     |              |          |          2015-2016 |        |    2017-2018 |        |
 |                     |              |          |       Transmission |        | Transmission |        |
 |                     |              |          |          Automatic | Manual |    Automatic | Manual |
 | ------------------- | ------------ | -------- | ------------------ | ------ | ------------ | ------ |
 | Number of cylinders |            4 | row_perc |               13.6 |   36.4 |         13.6 |   36.4 |
 |                     |            6 | row_perc |               28.6 |   21.4 |         28.6 |   21.4 |
 |                     |            8 | row_perc |               42.9 |    7.1 |         42.9 |    7.1 |
 |                     | #Total cases | row_perc |               19.0 |   13.0 |         19.0 |   13.0 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
library(expss)

data(mtcars)

mtcars$period <- "2015-2016"
mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
mtcars$period[33:64] <- "2017-2018"

mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      period = "Measurement period"
)

mtcars %>% 
  tab_cells(cyl) %>% 
  tab_cols(period %nest% am ) %>% 
  tab_subgroup(period =="2015-2016") %>%
  tab_stat_rpct(label = "row_perc") %>%
  tab_subgroup(period =="2017-2018") %>%
  tab_stat_rpct(label = "row_perc") %>%
  tab_pivot(stat_position = "inside_rows")
```

Pay attention to the use of `tab_subgroup()` which determines which subgroup of year period we want to calculate the percentage as well as to `stat_position = "inside_rows"` which determines where we want to put the calculated output in the final table.

Output:

```
 |                     |              |          | Measurement period |        |              |        |
 |                     |              |          |          2015-2016 |        |    2017-2018 |        |
 |                     |              |          |       Transmission |        | Transmission |        |
 |                     |              |          |          Automatic | Manual |    Automatic | Manual |
 | ------------------- | ------------ | -------- | ------------------ | ------ | ------------ | ------ |
 | Number of cylinders |            4 | row_perc |               27.3 |   72.7 |              |        |
 |                     |              |          |                    |        |         27.3 |   72.7 |
 |                     |            6 | row_perc |               57.1 |   42.9 |              |        |
 |                     |              |          |                    |        |         57.1 |   42.9 |
 |                     |            8 | row_perc |               85.7 |   14.3 |              |        |
 |                     |              |          |                    |        |         85.7 |   14.3 |
 |                     | #Total cases | row_perc |               19.0 |   13.0 |              |        |
 |                     |              |          |                    |        |         19.0 |   13.0 |
```

**EDIT:**

We do not need `%nest%` if we do not want nested rows(*i.e.* twice more rows). In this case, the final part of the code should be modified as follows:

```
mtcars %>% 
  tab_cells(cyl) %>% 
  tab_cols(period,am) %>% 
  tab_subgroup(period ==c("2015-2016")) %>%
  tab_stat_rpct(label = "row_perc") %>%
  tab_subgroup(period ==c("2017-2018")) %>%
  tab_stat_rpct(label = "row_perc") %>%
  tab_pivot(stat_position = "outside_columns")
```

Output:

```
 |                     |              | Measurement period | Transmission |          |           |
 |                     |              |          2015-2016 |    Automatic |   Manual | Automatic |
 |                     |              |           row_perc |     row_perc | row_perc |  row_perc |
 | ------------------- | ------------ | ------------------ | ------------ | -------- | --------- |
 | Number of cylinders |            4 |                100 |         27.3 |     72.7 |      27.3 |
 |                     |            6 |                100 |         57.1 |     42.9 |      57.1 |
 |                     |            8 |                100 |         85.7 |     14.3 |      85.7 |
 |                     | #Total cases |                 32 |         19.0 |     13.0 |      19.0 |

          | Measurement period |
   Manual |          2017-2018 |
 row_perc |           row_perc |
 -------- | ------------------ |
     72.7 |                100 |
     42.9 |                100 |
     14.3 |                100 |
     13.0 |                 32 |
```

Comment: Thank Vitali! The row percentages are indeed calculated as desired, however as a side-effect the number of rows in the tables has doubled. The data for 2017-2018 is one row below the data for 2015-2016. Currently not a big deal, but with more time periods this could lead to a lot of rows and a not-so-good-looking table. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I will look into that, @Steffen

Comment: @Steffen I made an edit. Please, let me know if that's what you want.